# Binding UserControl inside a ListView datatemplate WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

So i have this issue:

- I have created a UserControl (basically a textbox and label). This user control I am able to Bind using a Dependency Property.
- I have a ListView in which I can put a textbox in the datatemplate and bind the "text" property to the binded value.

so far so good. but now if I try to put the UserControl into that very same scenario the DependencyProperty stops working.

Here is the code: **[ListView]**

```
<ListView x:Name="DtContactDetailListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <UserControl:tbx label="{Binding detail}" text="{Binding value}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The binding in this situation works when its outside the listview, in other parts of the form... so its not an issue with my DepedencyProperty. Also substituting the UserControl for a Textbox, and adding the exact same Binding also works. But it doesn't work under this... why?!

UPDATE
As requested, I have updated the code for the UserControl. Keep in mind this works perfectly when binding it to other elements on the window or page. Just doesn't work inside a listview.

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.DataContext = Me
End Sub

'TextBox property
Public Shared ReadOnly tbxTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("text", GetType([String]), GetType(tbx), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(String.Empty))
Public Property text() As [String]
    Get
        Return GetValue(tbxTextProperty).ToString()
    End Get
    Set(value As [String])
        SetValue(tbxTextProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Post code for your UserControl. Code here seems fine.

Comment: What is `UserControl:tbx`? Maybe `tbx:UserControl`?

Comment: UserControl is the name of my project where i keep usercontrols and tbx is the name of the usercontrol itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comment issue is in your UserControl, you have explicitly set `DataContext` of userControl to itself:

```
Me.DataContext = Me
```

So, binding `label="{Binding detail}"` **looking for property `detail` in dataContext of UserControl (itself) and not in underlying dataContext of ListBoxItem**.

You have to do explicit binding in case you want to look for item in DataContext of ListBoxItem like:

```
label="{Binding DataContext.detail,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
```

**OR**

You should remove setting `DataContext` to itself in UserControl.

You must have set it to bind with declared DP's. I would suggest to **bind that using `ElementName` and remove setting DataContext.** That way you don't have to give explicit binding and your UserControl will automatically inherit DataContext from its Visual parent.

```
<UserControl x:Name="myUserControl">
   <Label Content="{Binding label, ElementName=myUserControl}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding text, ElementName=myUserControl}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: great. so removing the DataContext did the trick. i'll follow your second advice, and see if it solves my problem all together!