# binding a Custom control in DataTemplate

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've been tackling a problem regarding databinding in XAML for a little while now.

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pedagouge.Views;assembly=Pedagouge"
             x:Class="Pedagouge.Views.StudentGroupView">
  <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="Students">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <local:PhotoView x:Name="Photo" Persona="{Binding}" />
              <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding StudentIsAt.Group.Name}" />
              </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I thought I had binding figured, but the problem I'm having clearly shows that I'm not.
Anyways, the problem is that for the custom control `PhotoView` it seems that the binding context used by `{Binding}` to the property `Persona` is the `PhotoView`'s `BindingContext`, not the `DataTemplate`'s context, as it is for the `Label`s a couple of rows down.

Had this been WPF, I would have just changed the binding to

```xml
Persona="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
```

and that would probably have fixed it, but that won't work here (RelativeSource is apparently not defined).

How come? How can I make `Persona` bound to the `DataTemplate`s context, as is the case with the `Label`s, instead?

Comment: What if you add a property `Self { get { return this; } }` on your viewmodel, then change the binding on PhotoView.Persona to `{Binding Self}`?  Also.. have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595388/binding-usercontrol-inside-a-listview-datatemplate-wpf

Comment: @mrtig Sounds like that would still give me a reference to the view model, and not the item currently being bound to the DataTemplate

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. You could try the "self" property on each member of the bound collection. ..Or you could try the `ElementName` suggestion (in the above link).

Comment: The `ElementName` solution only generates `NullPointerException`. I did move the entire ViewCell into its own control first.

Answer (score 4):

`Xamarin.Forms` (up to 1.2.x) bindings always use the BindableObject.BindingContext as the context binding.

In the case of templates items, the item context is set to the template element, in this case the `ViewCell`, and recursively to the `ViewCell.View`, the `StackLayout`, **your `PhotoView`**, the inner `StackLayout` and the 2 `Label`s.

The fact that `FullName` and `StudentIsAt.Group.Name` works is a strong hint.

So, when you say

```
[...] for the custom control PhotoView it seems that the binding context used by 
{Binding} to the property Persona is the PhotoView's BindingContext, not the 
DataTemplate's context, [...]
```

it's both true and wrong.

The binding context used by `{Binding}` is the PhotoView's Bindingcontext, **which is also the DataTemplate's context.**

If the Binding does not work as you expect, it's probably because `PhotoView` somehow set the `BindingContext` to `this`, and prevent the `{Binding}` to work as expected, but I can't say without seeing `PhotoView`'s code.

Comment: `PhotoView` did set the `BindingContext`, but to a `ViewModel` class. I have since removed that ViewModel and then it all worked as I expected it to (i.e. as it did for the `Label`s binding).

Comment: if you're ok with the answer, accept it. it might help others